# Error in scipy wilcoxon signed rank test for equal series?

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I have a problem with the results of scipy.wilcoxon signed rank test;

```
x1=[29.39958, 29.21756, 29.350915, 29.34911, 29.212635]
sp.wilcoxon(x1,x1,zero_method="wilcox",correction=True)
```

returns statistic=0.0, pvalue=nan

But with zero_method="pratt", it returns statistic=0.0,  pvalue=0.043114446783075355 instead.
I think there is a mistake there.
The statistics (for z-score, if I am not mistaken) are the same, but the results are different for the p-value.

Am I right and scipy wrong or am I missing something?!
I wanted to check with another module, but neither alglib's (http://www.alglib.net/hypothesistesting/wilcoxonsignedrank.php) or statmodels' (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.descstats.sign_test.html?highlight=wilcoxon) allows for pratt correction, which I needed as it was deemed as more conservative...
Could you also advice for alternative modules for python stats? Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `x1` twice in the call to wilcoxon? The diff between x1 and x1 is indentically zero and there are only ties. If you want to test symmetry around mean then, I think, it should be `wilcoxon(x1 - x1.mean(), zero_...)` or use median instead of mean.

Comment: This is just an example to show the broken case. When series of input are identical, pratt ordering procedure breaks, for what I understand.